# Selecting something not initially selected in a document

Tags: mongoose

If I run a query like this:

```
Thing.findOne().select('name').exec(function (err, doc) {  
})
```

…then I can access `doc.name` from the callback, and not `doc.bigstuff`. There is a miniscule chance that I will need to access `doc.bigstuff`, and it is often over 800KB, so I don't want to query it if I don't need it. I see in the docs that I can do this:

```
Thing.findOne().select('name').exec(function (err, doc) {
   doc.isSelected('name') // true
   doc.isSelected('bigstuff')  // false
})
```

…to find out if I have selected `doc.bigstuff`, but I can find no explanation about how to add it to the selection (preferably just for this document). Sorry if there is an obvious answer, I'm not seeing anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add that field to an existing result.  You'd have to requery for the doc with `findOne` again with that field included in the select string.

```js
Thing.findOne({_id: doc._id}).select('name bigstuff').exec(function (err, doc) {
   doc.isSelected('name') // true
   doc.isSelected('bigstuff')  // true
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I feared that might be the case. By the way, why not use `Thing.findById`?

Comment: @JJ56 `findById` is fine too; it's just a shortcut for the same query.